# Codeigniter 4 JSON Pagination

Tags: codeigniter-4

Using Codeigniter 4 I am creating pagination but it returns rendered HTML when i try

```php
<?= $pager->makeLinks($page, $perPage, $total) ?>
```

How can I get JSON data instead of this HTML

Answer (score 1):

`makeLink` function returns the HTML markup. To return the JSON object you have to use `$pager->getDetails()`. This function returns the array which can be converted into JSON as follows

```php
return json_encode(['pager' => $pager->getDetails()]);
```

This simply converts the array into a JSON object which you can handle using JavaScript. You can also use Response object to convert it into JSON as follow :

```php
$this->response->setContentType('application/json')->setJSON(['pager' => $pager->getDetails()])->send();
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at my code:

```php
$parpage=10;
$page=1;
$offset=0;
$this->model->where('id', $id)->paginate($perpage'default',$page,$offset);
```

Answer (score 0):

On your controller call the pager library & the model 
Create an array for passing the data on the view like the code below:

```php
    public function samplePager() {

       $yourModel = new modelName();

       $pager = \Config\Services::pager();

         $data = [
            'users' => $yourModel->paginate(10),
            'pager' => $yourModel->pager,
        ];

        return view('users/index', $data);
    }
```

On your view file sample users/index.php you must put this after the `foreach()` loop on the page

```php
      <?php foreach($users as $user): ?>
         

      <?php endforeach; ?>

      <?= $pager->links() ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a **.json** is file inside **/public/data** folder.

> **Controller**

Open any controller, say **SiteController.php** and write this complete code into it.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Controllers\BaseController;
use App\Models\CountryModel;

class SiteController extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $json = file_get_contents("data/countries-data.json");
        $countries = json_decode($json);

        $object = new CountryModel;

        foreach ($countries->countries as $key => $value) {
            $object->insert([
                "sortname" => $value->sortname,
                "name" => $value->name,
                "phonecode" => $value->phoneCode
            ]);
        }

        $paginateData = $object->paginate(5);

        $data = [
            'countries' => $paginateData,
            'pager' => $object->pager,
            'search' => $search
        ];

        return view('countries', $data);
    }
}
```

By above code, reading .json file and sending paginated data to view.

> **View**

```php
<table class="table table-hover" style='border-collapse: collapse;'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Shortname</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        foreach ($countries as $dt) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $dt['id'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $dt['sortname'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $dt['name'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>

<!-- Paginate -->
<div style='margin-top: 10px;'>
    <?= $pager->links() ?>
</div>
```

I hope it will help you.